# JPA + MySQL - column value generated by database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using column with GENERATED ALWAYS AS formula. When I try to save entity value using JPA i get

```
java.sql.SQLException: The value specified for generated column 'bucket' in table 'discover_cache' is not allowed.
```

class definition:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "discover_cache")
@IdClass(DiscoverCacheId.class)
public class DiscoverCache {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 36)
    private String userId;

    @Id
    private int postId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (floor(TO_SECONDS(`created_date`) / 900) % 17) STORED NOT NULL")
    @Id
    private short bucket;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "DATETIME(3)")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    public DiscoverCache(String userId, int postId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.postId = postId;
    }
}

@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DiscoverCacheId implements Serializable {

    @Column(length = 36)
    private String userId;

    private int postId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (floor(TO_SECONDS(`created_date`) / 900) % 17) STORED NOT NULL")
    private short bucket;

    public DiscoverCacheId(String userId, int postId, short bucket) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.postId = postId;
        this.bucket = bucket;
    }
}
```

How can I tell JPA to ignore this value on persist so that I can be calculated by the database? I could of course use native query to save it, but I wanted to use JpaRepository<>

Comment: Change the type to `Short` rather than `short` and (asuming you are using HIbernate as JPA provider) annotate your entity with `@DynamicInsert` and/or `@DynamicUpdate` which exclude nulls from insert/update statements.

Answer (score 2):

set insertable and updateable to false.

```
@Column(name="user_id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
var userId: Long? = null
```